# How to check if variable is of type function Number() or function String() js

Tags: javascript

In javascript. How can I test if a variable is equal to `function Number()` or `function String()`.

I reading a react prop from a schema definition for which the type is set as a property. Thus a have `this.props.fieldType` is a `function Number()` or `function String()`.

I have tried:

```
 if(this.props.fieldType instanceof Number)
```

and

```
if(Object.getPrototypeOf(this.props.fieldType) === Number.prototype)
```

according to 
[instanceof description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) but this does not work. Not sure why.

Comment: Are you trying to check if the value is a number (like `1`) or a string (like `"foo"`)?

Comment: no. trying to check if the property has a value of `function Number()` of `function String()`

Comment: Your `instanceof` check will only return `true` if your `fieldType` was created using either `new Number()` or `new String()`. Is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> trying to check if the property has a value of `function Number()` of `function String()`

If you literally mean **the functions** `Number` or `String`, use `==` (or `===`):

```
if (this.props.fieldType === Number) {
```

If you mean "is it a number" or "is it a string", use `typeof`, not `instanceof`:

```
if (typeof this.props.fieldType === "number") {
```

If you mean "is it a object created via new `Number`" (which would be really unusual) then `instanceof` is what you want:

```
if (this.props.fieldType instanceof Number) {
```

Examples of all three:

```js
var props = {
  numberFunction: Number,
  number: 42,
  numberObject: new Number(42)
};
console.log(props.numberFunction === Number);
console.log(typeof props.number === "number");
console.log(props.numberObject instanceof Number);
```

---

You mentioned `instanceof` in relation to doing `getPrototypeOf` and an equality comparison. It's imporant to understand that those are very different things.

`instanceof` checks to see if the object (the left-hand operand) has the current `prototype` property of the function (the right-hand operand) *anywhere* in its prototype chain. It may not be the object's immediate prototype; it may be further down. For example:

```js
function Thing() {
}
var t = new Thing();
// The following is true, Object.prototype is in t's prototype chain
console.log(t instanceof Object);
// The following is false, t's prototype isn't Object.prototype;
// Object.prototype is further down t's prototype chain
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(t) === Object.prototype);
```